# Recommendations for a browser-based frontend implementation

Tags: gis, react, vue.js

We are planning to set up a new browser-based mapping application from scratch.

Our requirements are

- OpenLayers as the map framework
- the application should be somehow futureproof for a couple of years

But for the general frontend framework we are still not decided.

We are somehow tending to React. This is because of the experience and knowledge that exists within the team. But there are other options like e.g. SvelteKit or Vue.js on the table. I also thought about GeoDjango.

If we take the consideration about existing framework knowledge in the team aside, what are best recommendations for a browser based application in 2023?